# How to extract array of Strings from ServerRequest in Spring reactive Webflux

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have an array of Strings which are coming in the POST Body from postman/client, I need to convert it to array/List for further using.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getArray(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    final Flux<String> personPhotoFlux = serverRequest
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

    return ServerResponse.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
}
```

This is returning the whole array as string.
Example of Body

```
["123",
"456"]
```

resultant String

```
"[\"123\",\"456\"]"
```

I need them as List<String>

Answer (score 0):

This is working.

```
serverRequest.bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() { })
                    .flatMapMany(this::printMethod);
```